New Vote Types in latest data dump?
As I was looking through the latest StackExchange data dump, I noticed that in the StackOverflow dump there are a few new VoteTypeIds: 19,29,30,31,32,33
There is no mention of them in SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1856026
They do not seem to be showing up in any of the other site dumps. What do these new Vote Types represent?

If this is an intentional change, this is why it's important to include documentation with the data dumps. The meaning of these should be available without reliance on the network, since one point of the data dump is to ensure accessibility of the content should something happen to the network.

If they are only on Stack Overflow, then I guess they are related to SO-exclusive Discussions and/or Staging Ground (if it's included). When did they start appearing?

@MetaAndrewT. They are all over the place. Some are as old as 2010, and others are very recent.

They seem to be 19:“thankYou”, 29:“Outdated”, 30:“notOutdated”, 31: “preVote”, 32/33:“collectiveDiscussionUpvote/Downvote”

Looking in full.en.js, which should be ok to do as this answer did the same, we find a list of VoteTypeIds:
var VoteTypeId;
(function (VoteTypeId) {
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["informModerator"] = -1] = "informModerator";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["undoMod"] = 0] = "undoMod";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["acceptedByOwner"] = 1] = "acceptedByOwner";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["upMod"] = 2] = "upMod";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["downMod"] = 3] = "downMod";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["offensive"] = 4] = "offensive";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["bookmark"] = 5] = "bookmark";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["close"] = 6] = "close";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["reopen"] = 7] = "reopen";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["bountyClose"] = 9] = "bountyClose";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["deletion"] = 10] = "deletion";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["undeletion"] = 11] = "undeletion";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["spam"] = 12] = "spam";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["reaction1"] = 17] = "reaction1";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["helpful"] = 18] = "helpful";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["thankYou"] = 19] = "thankYou";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["wellWritten"] = 20] = "wellWritten";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["follow"] = 21] = "follow";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["reaction2"] = 22] = "reaction2";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["reaction3"] = 23] = "reaction3";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["reaction4"] = 24] = "reaction4";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["reaction5"] = 25] = "reaction5";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["reaction6"] = 26] = "reaction6";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["reaction7"] = 27] = "reaction7";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["reaction8"] = 28] = "reaction8";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["outdated"] = 29] = "outdated";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["notOutdated"] = 30] = "notOutdated";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["preVote"] = 31] = "preVote";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["collectiveDiscussionUpvote"] = 32] = "collectiveDiscussionUpvote";
    VoteTypeId[VoteTypeId["collectiveDiscussionDownvote"] = 33] = "collectiveDiscussionDownvote";
})(VoteTypeId || (VoteTypeId = {}));

Therefore, the VoteTypeIds mean the following:

19: “thankYou” is the thank you reaction
29: “outdated” and 30: “notOutdated” are likely from the Outdated Answers project where outdated flags could be cast.
31: “preVote”
32: “collectiveDiscussionUpvote” and 33 “collectiveDiscussionDownvote” are for voting on collective discussions, but the downvote option was removed.


It's possible that 13-16 were related to documentation, @testing-for-ya - considering the chronological nature of the numbers. Since the project was sunset, it's not unlikely that much of the data was removed, including the vote IDs.
